# Same value entered in the database even on sending different values

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

im making a form on php which saves data into the database
here is the code for it where i send data from php form to the database:

```
<?php
$users_name = $_POST['name'];
$users_email = $_POST['email'];
$users_phoneNumber = $_POST['phNo'];
$users_cnic = $_POST['cnic'];
$users_voucherNumber = $_POST['vNum'];
$users_modelNumber = $_POST['prod'];


if( $_POST )
        {

          $dbhost = "localhost";
          $dbuser = "root";
          $dbpassword = "";
          $dbname = "dany";
          $query = "";
          $sqlQuery = ""; 


          $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);

          if ($conn->connect_error) {
              die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
          } 


          echo ("Variables values: " . " "  . $users_cnic . " " . 
                          $users_phoneNumber . "<br>");
          $query = "INSERT INTO customer( c_name, c_phoneNumber, c_cnic, 
                    c_email, c_voucherNumber, c_modelNumber) VALUES 
                     ('$users_name','$users_phoneNumber', '$users_cnic', 
                    '$users_email', $users_voucherNumber, 
                       '$users_modelNumber')";

          if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
              //if successful
            echo ("Variables values after success: " . " "  . $users_cnic . 
                   " " . $users_phoneNumber . "<br>");
          } else {
              //if data not successfully entered
              echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
          }

          $conn->close();

        }

?>
```

but the problem is when i try to send data, same value for "c_phoneNumber" and "c_cnic" is sent every single time which is "2147483647". i.e every row in the table has two columns and each of this column has value "2147483647".

if you see the line which i have witten to check the values if they are correct:

```
echo ("Variables values: " . " "  . $users_cnic . " " . $users_phoneNumber . 
      "<br>");
```

here they have the values exactly the same as sent from the textboxes of the form. but when the query is made in the very next line of code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customer( c_name, c_phoneNumber, c_cnic, 
                    c_email, c_voucherNumber, c_modelNumber) VALUES 
                     ('$users_name','$users_phoneNumber', '$users_cnic', 
                    '$users_email', $users_voucherNumber, 
                       '$users_modelNumber')";
```

both these variables hold "2147483647".

and when the if statment runs after successfully entering the data into table:

```
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
              //if successful
            echo ("Variables values after success: " . " "  . $users_cnic . 
                   " " . $users_phoneNumber . "<br>");
          }
```

it has the same values which have been passed from the text boxes.
i cannot figure out the problem the variable data remains the same throughout the programs running state but when inserted into the database changes.

i have tried:

1- creating a new table

2- creating two new columns

3- sending hard coded values.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO customer( c_name, c_phoneNumber, c_cnic, 
                    c_email, c_voucherNumber, c_modelNumber) VALUES 
                     ('$users_name',123, 456, 
                    '$users_email', $users_voucherNumber, 
                       '$users_modelNumber')";
```

and when i do this step no 4, the values are perfectly send and inserted which are 123, 456.

4- creating a new query, saving it in an other variable, running the query = same results.(error)

Comment: Learn about prepared Statement to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Jens is right, your code is wide open to hacking. A malicious user could input data which could steal, delete or corrupt your data. Use prepared statements and parameters to protect your database. It's easy to find tutorials for this online.

Comment: You say it inserts "2147483647" in both fields. `'$users_phoneNumber', '$users_cnic'` indicates you're inserting strings (due to the quotes round the variables). But your hard-coded example inserts integers. What is the data type of each of these fields in the database? What are the values of each of the textboxes when you do the insert? Could be a string/integer mismatch. If you'd used parameters, as you ought to, this kind of data type mismatch would go away.

Comment: @Jens i have tried doing what you hinted. it worked for 2 to 3 entries, but then the same problem started occurring again

Comment: @ADyson, each of these 2 fields is integer in the database. i have tried removing the quotes, it does enter integer but only "2147483647". when i do the insertion, the values are defferent integers every single time. i do not repeat an input. the textbox input type is declared "number" in the html code. it does not allow any string/keystroke other then numerals.

Comment: How big are these integers you're inserting? 2147483647 is the max (signed) value for an INT field in MySQL. Any number larger than that will be reset to that max value. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html. You can use the BIGINT type if you need to store bigger numbers.

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot. this did work. i was using INTEGER as datatype and entering a value greater then "2147483647" that was why is was reset tothe max value. no when i have changed integer datatype to "bigint", the problem is solved. i have wasted all my day today on this thing.
thank you so much for the help ADyson

Comment: No problem, I have posted as an answer, I would be grateful if you would mark as accepted, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2147483647 is the max (signed) value for an INT field in MySQL. Any number larger than that will be reset to that max value. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html. You can use the `BIGINT` type if you need to store bigger numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Try This brother hope it will help you

```
<?php
$users_name = $_POST['name'];
$users_email = $_POST['email'];
$users_phoneNumber = $_POST['phNo'];
$users_cnic = $_POST['cnic'];
$users_voucherNumber = $_POST['vNum'];
$users_modelNumber = $_POST['prod'];

if(!empty($_POST['name']))
{
          $dbHost = "localhost";
          $dbUsername = "nextgbsl_pay";
          $dbPassword = "Welive@2017";
          $dbName = "nextgbsl_tbl_payment";



          $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
           //Display error if failed to connect
       if ($db->connect_errno) {
           printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db->connect_error);
             exit();
                   } 

echo ("Variables values: " . " "  . $users_cnic . " " . 
                          $users_phoneNumber . "<br>");
            $query =  $db->query("INSERT INTO customer( c_name, c_phoneNumber, c_cnic, 
                    c_email, c_voucherNumber, c_modelNumber) VALUES 
                     ('".$users_name."','".$users_phoneNumber."', '".$users_cnic."', 
                    '".$users_email."', '".$users_voucherNumber."', 
                       '".$users_modelNumber."')";);


          if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
              //if successful
            echo ("Variables values after success: " . " "  . $users_cnic . 
                   " " . $users_phoneNumber . "<br>");
          } else {
              //if data not successfully entered
              echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
          }

          mysqli_close($con);


}

?>
```

Comment: lots of code, but no explanation of why it would help. This would be of minimal use to the OP or future readers, they would just copy/paste without learning, so not a great quality answer. Also it misses the key point about the size of the integers being used, and fails to fix the SQL Injection vulnerability or even to make the inserted values be passed as ints instead of strings. As far as I can see all this does is use slightly different PHP syntax to concatenate the strings together, which adds no value at all.

Comment: thanks a lot brother. the problem was the datatype i was using in my database. "2147483647" was the maximum value of an integer datatype, i changed it to BIGINT, it solved the pronlem. thanks for looking into the matter anyways